# SPARQL: Specify datatype in INSERT query

Tags: sparql, rdf

Let's same I want to add via a SPARQL query these triples to my graph

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/ontology#">

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http:/example.com/entity/thisEntity">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://example.com/ontology#Identification" />
    <my:someID rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">003</my:someID>
    <my:hasSource  rdf:resource="http:/example.com/entity/thisSource" />
  </rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

How am I supposed to specify the data type of the third triple?

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX my: <http://example.com/ontology#>

INSERT DATA {
              <http:/example.com/entity/thisEntity> rdf:type <http://example.com/ontology#Identification>;
                                                 my:hasSource  <http:/example.com/entity/thisSource>;
                                                 my:someID "003"@xsd:string.

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The `@` is for language tags. Datatypes are appended by using the `^^` separator instead. So use `"003"^^xsd:string`.

You will also need to add the namespace prefix to your update:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
```

As an aside: in RDF 1.1, `xsd:string` is the default datatype for any literal that does not have an explicitly defined datatype nor a language tag. So `"003"` and `"003"^^xsd:string` are both the same, string-typed, literal.